# Returning a case when the unix time value has elapsed (in the past)

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a button with a different link state depending on the time. I use a value from the database which is the start time and then work out the remaining seconds and change the display using a switch statement.

So before the current time, the button has no link, when it's less than 60 seconds to the current time is a link, and after say, 8 hours since the data value, the link is different again. I've got it working nicely for everything before the time, and it changes when it is time, but I'm not sure how to change it once 8 hours are lapsed, entering a '-' before the value doesn't work. Here's my code which doesn't deal with when the time is 8 hours passed, the button doesn't change

```
protected function _join_meeting_button( $start_time, $url ) {

    // subtract the meeting start time from the current time
    
    // if it has started, return the join button with the join url  
    
    $remaining_seconds = $start_time - time();
    
    switch( $remaining_seconds ) {
        
            case ( $remaining_seconds < -86400 ) :
            
            $join_button = array( TC_LABEL => 'Ended', TC_URL => $url, TC_ICON => 'end' );
            
            break;

        case ( $remaining_seconds > -86400 && $remaining_seconds < 60 ) :
            
            $join_button = array( TC_LABEL => 'Join Meeting', TC_URL => $url, TC_ICON => 'play' );
            
            break;
            
        case ( $remaining_seconds > 60 && $remaining_seconds < 3600 ) :
            
            $join_button = array( TC_LABEL => round($remaining_seconds / 60) . ' min(s) to go', TC_ICON => 'clock' );
            
            break;

        case ( $remaining_seconds > 3600 && $remaining_seconds < 86400 ) :
            
            $join_button = array ( TC_LABEL => round($remaining_seconds / 3600) . ' hour(s) to go', TC_ICON => 'clock' );
            
            break;

        case ( $remaining_seconds > 86400 ) :
            
            $join_button = array ( TC_LABEL => round($remaining_seconds / 86400) . ' day(s) to go', TC_ICON => 'clock' );
            
            break;

    }
    
    return $join_button;

}
```

I'm pretty sure it's because this bit is wrong:

```
$remaining_seconds > -86400
```

So I'm struggling on how to handle the negative integer?

Thank you.

Comment: This isn’t a use case for `switch`, use `if..else if..else`.

Comment: Or `switch( ture ) {`

Comment: 86400 seconds is 24 hours, not 8 hours.

Comment: yes sorry I know 86400 is 24 hours. Surely this is absolutely a case for a switch statement ?

Comment: `switch (A) case B` eventually means `if (A == B)`. So all your comparisons are `if ($remaining_seconds == ($remaining_seconds < -86400))`… You think that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

I'm so silly. Just realised, I just need a default, for when the situation drops through all the cases.

```
        default :
            
            $join_button = array ( TC_LABEL => 'Meeting Ended' );
            
            break;
```